# $(ab)c + a(bc) = 2 b (ac) \implies^? x(yz) = (xy)z$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, associativity, nonassociative-algebras

Consider some unital commutative algebra $A$ such that for all its elements we have

$$(ab)c + a(bc) = 2 b (ac) $$

Does this imply the algebra is associative ?

or in symbols :

$$(ab)c + a(bc) = 2 b (ac) \implies^? x(yz) = (xy)z$$

Comment: The bit beginning "or in symbols" doesn't add anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following shows that the algebra is associative whenever the multiplication is distributive and 6 is not a zero-divisor.

Taking $a=b$ gives $(aa)c=a(ac)$. Next taking $a=b=x+y$ and $c=z$ in this new relation and using commutativity and distributivity gives
$$ (x^2+y^2+2xy)z = (x+y)(xz+yz) = x(xz) + y(yz) + x(yz)+ y(xz), $$
so that
$$ x(yz)+y(xz) = 2(xy)z. $$
Finally, we have
$$ 2b(ac) - a(bc) = (ab)c = (ba)c = 2a(bc) - b(ac), $$
so that
$$ 3a(bc) = 3b(ac). $$
Thus, as 6 is a not a zero divisor, we get $x(yz)=y(xz)$, which combined with the earlier relation gives $2x(yz)=2(xy)z$, and hence $x(yz)=(xy)z$.

Comment: Excuse me, does the 2nd display-style formula not follow from the problem statement immediately? (the ring is commutative) Also, don't we need just 3 instead of 6 from the 4th formula?

Comment: Yes, it does :) We need 6, though, since in the last line we need to cancel the 2.

Comment: From formula 4 and commutativity we get $3(bc)a=3a(bc)=3b(ac)=3b(ca)$, however...

Comment: Nice. Accepted.